# How to Add Continuous Camera Movement in React Three Fiber?

Tags: three.js, react-three-fiber

I'm a student learning React Three Fiber, and I'm looking to enhance my portfolio by adding camera movement. I'm wondering how I can achieve a continuous camera movement, similar to the example site provided (https://cineshader.com/).

What approach should I take to create this continuous camera movement effect? Any guidance or code examples would be greatly

and I'm looking to connect with communities and find resources for learning more about Three.js, Babylon.js, and PlayCanvas. Are there dedicated forums or websites where I can interact with others who are working with these libraries and find tutorials, documentation, and helpful tips?

Any suggestions or recommendations for active communities and valuable resources would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.